# Getting difference between two dates from 2 REF'd columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to get the date between 2 values between two REF'd column values.
I currently have the tables set up like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person_Type AS OBJECT
(PersonId NUMBER,
DateBorn DATE)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Movie_Type AS OBJECT
(MovieId NUMBER,
ReleaseDate DATE)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Role_Type AS OBJECT
(PersonId REF Person_Type,
MovieId REF Movie_Type,
Name VARCHAR2(40),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Actor_Age RETURN NUMBER)
```

**The data is inserted like this:**

```
INSERT INTO Person_Table
VALUES (10000, '11-NOV-1974')

INSERT INTO Movie_Table
VALUES(1000000, '19-DEC-1997')

INSERT INTO Role_Table
VALUES((SELECT REF(a) FROM Person_Table a WHERE a.PersonId = 10000),
(SELECT REF(b) FROM Movie_Table b WHERE b.MovieId = 1000000),
'Some Person')
```

I'm trying to get the method Actor_Age to return the difference between the day someone is born and the date the movie got released. I've tried the below but it won't compile..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Role_Type
AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Actor_Age
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
    RETURN (MONTHS_BETWEEN((SELECT g.PersonId.DateBorn FROM Role_Table g),
(SELECT f.MovieId.Releasedate FROM Role_Table f)/12));
     END;
 END;
```

Comment: Post DDL for 3 tables as well.

Comment: Updated. You meant for the table INSERT right?

Comment: No. I need table DDL(structure script) of tables `Movie_Table` ,`Person_Table` and `Role_Table`

Comment: @XING - It is self evident from the types - `CREATE TABLE Person_table OF Person_Type;`

Comment: @MT0. That is what i wanted from OP in question before giving any solution.

Comment: @lesovren `'11-NOV-1974'` is not a `DATE` it is a String literal - Oracle will try to implicitly convert it to a date using `TO_DATE` and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model; however, that session parameter can be changed by the user at any time and will vary its default value across different countries and languages (leading to interesting and hard to debug issues). It is better practice to either use date literals `DATE '1974-11-11'` or to explicitly state the format model (and language) `TO_DATE( '11-NOV-1974', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1b19/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person_Type AS OBJECT
(PersonId NUMBER,
DateBorn DATE)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Movie_Type AS OBJECT
(MovieId NUMBER,
ReleaseDate DATE)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Role_Type AS OBJECT
(PersonId REF Person_Type,
MovieId REF Movie_Type,
Name VARCHAR2(40),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Actor_Age RETURN NUMBER)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Role_Type
AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Actor_Age
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    p_age NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(
             DEREF( MovieID ).ReleaseDate,
             DEREF( PersonID ).DateBorn
           ) / 12
    INTO   p_age
    FROM   DUAL;
    RETURN p_age;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE Person_Table OF Person_Type
/
CREATE TABLE Movie_Table OF Movie_Type
/
CREATE TABLE Role_Table OF Role_Type
/

INSERT INTO Person_Table VALUES ( 10000, DATE '1970-01-01' )
/
INSERT INTO Movie_Table VALUES ( 1000000, DATE '2000-01-01' )
/
INSERT INTO Role_Table VALUES(
  (SELECT REF(a) FROM Person_Table a WHERE a.PersonId = 10000),
  (SELECT REF(b) FROM Movie_Table b WHERE b.MovieId = 1000000),
  'Some Person'
)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name,
       r.Actor_Age()
FROM   Role_table r
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1b19/2/0)**:

```
|        NAME | R.ACTOR_AGE() |
|-------------|---------------|
| Some Person |            30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In pl sql you have to use construction `select into`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Role_Type
AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Actor_Age
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
    v_date_born date ;
    v_realse_date date ;
   BEGIN
     SELECT deref(self.PersonId).DateBorn into v_date_born  FROM dual;
    SELECT deref(self.MovieId).Releasedate into v_realse_date FROM dual;
    RETURN (MONTHS_BETWEEN(v_date_born,v_realse_date)/12);
     END;
 END;
```

Comment: This will not work - `Role_Table` can have multiple rows and you are not filtering them to the current row (apart from the fact that you do not need to select from the entire table as the object is the table row and you can just use the object's attributes) and you cannot use `PersonId.DateBorn` when `PersonID` is a `REF` - you need to use `DEREF( PersonId ).DateBorn`.